# Does anyone has some code for Mathematica or Python to convert a diagonal matrix into Dirac (bra-ket) notation?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms

I have the following matrix which I have to translate into Dirac's notations.
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(q_0+q_3\right){}^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_0-q_3\right){}^2 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right) \left(q_0+q_3\right) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right) \left(q_0-q_3\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right) \left(q_0+q_3\right) & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right) \left(q_0-q_3\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right){}^2 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right){}^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right){}^2 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right){}^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right) \left(q_0-q_3\right) & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right) \left(q_0+q_3\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1-q_2\right) \left(q_0-q_3\right) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_1+q_2\right) \left(q_0+q_3\right) & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(q_0-q_3\right){}^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(q_0+q_3\right){}^2 \\
\end{array}

It is diagonal and would be very nice if someone could help me. :)

Comment: this matrix is not diagonal though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the kets,

```
ket0 = {{1},{0}};ket1 = {{0},{1}};
```

This function produces input from a string,

```
f[x_?StringQ] := ToExpression[StringJoin["ket",x]];
```

This function produces the diagonal matrix  corresponding to a string "000",

```
matrixFunc[x_]:= KroneckerProduct@@ f/@ StringPartition[x,1] . 
ConjugateTranspose[KroneckerProduct@@ f/@ StringPartition[x,1] ] ;

matrixFunc["0001"];

A = RandomReal[1,{8,8}];M (* = INPUT MATRIX*);
```

This function gives the coefficient corresponding to the string (say) "001"

```
overlap[x_?StringQ]:= Tr[matrixFunc[x] .A];
```

All possible permutations in lexical (dictionary) order for comparison,

```
allkets = StringJoin/@ Tuples[{"0","1"},3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!